# How to get from the diminutive form to the root word (from Häuschen to Haus), and back?

Tags: noun, diminutive

Is there a rule (or best practice) on how to get from a "[Substantiv](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Hilfe:Substantiv)" to it´s [diminutive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutive) form and also back again?

What I mean is i.e: How to get from `Haus` to `Häuschen` and back to `Haus`.

It´s a [diminutive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutive) form. In German it´s a [Diminutiv](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutiv) (Verniedlichungsform, Verkleinerungsform)

This form is build from a noun and a suffix like: -lein, -chen, -ette, -erl.

The word `Häuschen` comes from `Haus`.
Singular: `das Haus`     ==> `das Häuschen`
Plural:     `die Häuser` ==> `die Häuschen`

Answer (score 4):

What I found till now is:

One approximation to get the root word:

- Remove -lein, -chen, -erl, -ette from the end of the word.
- Replace ä with a, ü with u, ö with o.
  If the word is a "zusammengesetztes Hauptwort" only replace the letters of the "Hauptwort" at the end.
- Add -e, -er, -en or nothing to the end of the word.

This does not cover all possibilities.

---

Examples:

[Kärtchen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kaertchen) to [Karte](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Karte)
1.) Kärt  (After removing the -chen)
2.) Kart  (After replacing ä with a)
3.) Karte (After adding -e)

[Häuschen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Haeuschen) to [Haus](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Haus)
1.) Häus (After removing -chen)
2.) Haus (After replacing ä with a)

[Kräutergärtchen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gaertchen) to [Kräutergarten](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kraeutergarten)
1.) Kräutergärt (After removing -chen)
2.) Kräutergart (After replacing ä of the last Hauptwort with a)
3.) Kräutergarten (After adding -en)

[Märchen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Maerchen) to [Mär](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Maer):
1.) Mär (After removing the -chen)

[Stiefelette](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Stiefelette) to [Stiefel](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Stiefel)
1.) Stiefel (After removing the -ette)

[Weckerl](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Weckerl) to [Wecken](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Wecken_Semmel_Brot_Backwerk)
1.) Weck (After removing the -erl)
2.) Wecken (After adding -en)

[Eichhörnchen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Eichhoernchen) to [Eichhorn](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Eichhorn)
1.) Eichhörn (After removing the -chen)
2.) Eichhorn (After replacing the ö with o)

---

An example where this approximation is wrong:

[Mädchen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Maedchen) to [Magd](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Magd):
1.) Mäd (After removing the -chen)
2.) Mad (After replacing the ä with a)
3.) You cant get to Magd by adding something to the end.

Comment: Can you give an example for replacing ß with s? I can't think of any and I think this replacement is wrong. For "Mädchen": Nowadays it isn't considered a diminutive of "Magd" anymore and its etymology is obscure for most speakers without any linguistic knowledge. If one did form a diminutive of Magd nowadays, it would be "Mägdchen/Mägdlein"; and furthermore "Mädchen" could (ironically) be analyzed as diminutive of "Made". For "Weckerl" you should know that this is a regional word and all three forms ("Weckerl", "Weck", "Wecken") are used (not necessarily in the same region).

Comment: In the olden days, i.e. before the last spelling reform, -ss was _verboten_ at the end of a word. You had to write _Schloß_, e.g., even though the diminutive would be (still is, in fact) _Schlösschen_. We spell it _Schloss_ these days, though.

Comment: @Ingmar: I think that's not what Andie2302 meant. Before his edit he had written that to recover the original word from the diminutive you have to replace ß by s. In any case, that's not true. Additionally, the Alte Rechtschreibung of Schlösschen was Schlößchen. With a ß as in Schloß.

Comment: Ja, es funktioniert nicht für "Mädchen", aber das Wort hat eh schon längst seine eigene Definition und die Herleitung ist den wenigsten bekannt. – Für jegliche 'Verniedlichungen' wie "Häuschen", "Gärtchen" usw. passt die Regel. +1 dafür.

Answer (score 3):

No, I'm afraid that there is no simple rule that covers all cases.

For some words there are even multiple diminuatives in use (sometimes regional variants, sometimes with slightly different meaning).

For the example of *Magd*, where your attempt also fails, Austrian German (i.e. the 39th edition of the "Österreichisches Wörterbuch") lists *Mäderl* as well as the dialect forms *Madl* and *Mädel* in addition to the Standard German *Mädchen*. Also, we use *Haserl* as well as *Häschen* for the diminuative of *Hase*.

I'm afraid you'll simply have to memorize these words and listen to native speakers for quite a while to get an intuitive feeling for how they are constructed in a certain region.

Comment: You are right that there are many variants to form a diminutive of a word: "-erl" with/without umlaut, "-el" with/without umlaut, "-chen" with umlaut; sometimes even several diminutive endings are combined. (I know the variant "Mädelchen" with both an "-el" and a "-chen".) In my understanding, the hard part about diminutives for non-native speakers is to recover the original word without the diminutive ending. By forming the diminutives, the last syllable containing a "schwa"-sound is dropped and it seems quite impossible to get it back without knowing the original word from the beginning.

Comment: @Chris I completely agree - there is no way of recovering the original word from a diminuative alone.